# Is anyone having success mixing scala and java files in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Is anyone having success mixing scala and java files in IntelliJ?

I am getting way too many strange errors...

Here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516673/cannot-run-file-located-outside-of-main-module-intellij-14-java-scala

And Here:

[IntelliJ 14 Java and Scala ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499132/intellij-14-java-and-scala-classnotfoundexception)

Files are mixed in same module.

Many posts online from -2011 are claiming the same sort of strange issues with mixing in the same project.  I feel real uneasy approaching scala if this has remained unresolved for years with no real articles explaining why.

I could be wrong, so I am asking the community for their experience.

Comment: We have been using IDEA for a long time, and in general it works just fine with scala, including mixed Java/Scala projects. But we have had some issues with 14.0 and decided to stay with 13.x until these issues are sorted out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, I have Apache Spark project (https://github.com/apache/spark) in my IntelliJ.

It uses standard maven directory that has `java` and `scala` directories under `src/main` of module directory.

[image]

Comment: How are the java and scala files organized?  Same module, or separate modules?

Comment: Works in the same module. I have a play2 scala project with Java code in the same directory with no issues.

Comment: This project worked fine for me. http://typesafe.com/activator/template/hello-play-scala . Created using the activator and then imported in intellij as an sbt project. I can Java classes to the same directory and compiles fine.

Comment: @BAR They're in the same module.

Comment: @Suztomo would you mind taking a screenshot of the directory tree?

Comment: @BAR Added a screenshot. Can you confirm the answer?

Comment: @Suztomo  I see the two separate Scala and Java directories, but I cannot tell they are in the same module from your screenshot.  I would like to see the Structure view in addition to this Project view.  BTW where is the .iml file located in your screenshot?

Comment: As you see in the screenshot, they're in the same module "spark-core_2.10". Although the screenshot didn't include .iml, IntelliJ automatically creates modules with .iml by reading pom.xml files. Would you try checking out spark project to see how it works?

Answer (score 2):

[image]Yes. I have several projects running in Intellij. Intellij does a good job of supporting mixed Java / Scala projects. I am not sure of any other IDE that better supports this.

If you are using scala IDE for eclipse, i suggest you to try Intellij.

Check the screen shot:

Comment: How are the java and scala files organized? Same module, or separate modules?

Comment: I think separate modules is key, it seems to be working now.  I have always used IntelliJ, could not stand some aspects of the Eclipse layout and workflow from a few years ago... from what I have heard, they copy well